# What could cause the Windows 'route' command to hang?

Tags: windows-7, routing

I've got a machine that I want to add a permanent route to.

The problem is that the route command just hangs when I run it in the dos console.

I'm launching the console as an administrator and then calling

```
route PRINT
```

just to verify the existing route.

This call never returns and never prints any output. Calling

```
route add ....
```

also does the same thing.

Is there anything that could cause this?

The machine is windows 7 64 bit and the user is not an administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth I'll leave a trail of what fixed this for me.

It turns out that there was a security patch from windows that didn't properly apply.  Each time the computer would restart it would show the "updating OS" message.

Rolling back windows to a known good state did the trick.

This is not a very gratifying "solution"